# Write in a csv values whitout a foreach

Tags: php, export-to-csv, php-5.6

I have this array :

```
$array = [
    'data' => [
        0 => 2678
        1 => 2378
    ],
    'active' => [
        0 => 866
        1 => 111
    ]
    ..........
]
```

I want to put in a csv like that

`data        active
2678         866
2378         111`

I tried like this :

```
fputcsv($fp,array_keys($array));
fputcsv($fp,array_values($array));
```

But something not working. I have only header shown in the csv, I mean only `data      active` whitout data. Please help me

Comment: Whats wrong with a foreach loop

Comment: How to that with foreach() ? I don't have in mind, how to write only once the key name of array

Comment: it didn't work because of your version of PHP. 5.3 does not support `[]`. Where you should have gotten an error about. Edit: This comment as per before the 2 revisions of php versions https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51879952/revisions

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry

Comment: this has gotten too many edits for whatever php version.

Comment: The `.........` bit is now worrying me. How many other arrays are in that array

Comment: A lot.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_values` doesn't do anything except return your existing array without any keys, so you're still passing a 2D array to `fputcsv`, which isn't something it can work with.

Fundamentally, you're looking to perform an operation on every "row" in your array. *This is absolutely what a foreach loop is for*, so I'm not sure why you'd be trying to avoid one. Unless you've got a very particular reason to avoid them (and I can't imagine what that might be), that's the structure you should be using.

To get your code working, all you need to do is wrap a loop around your second call to `fputcsv`:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

Edit:
Sorry, I didn't notice that the array was transposed in the question. If you want to work with that, you'll need to add the line:

```
$array = array_map(null, ...array_values($array));
```

before displaying the data.

See https://3v4l.org/AoRcQ for a full example.

Comment: If I get you example :
$array = [
    'data' => [
        0 => 2678,
        1 => 2378,
    ],
    'active' => [
        0 => 866,
        1 => 111,
    ],
];
The correct return should be : 
`data,active 

  2678,866 
  2378,111`

Comment: @George I see now. I've updated the answer and example.

Comment: Add this line : `$array = array_map(null, array_values($array));` before foreach ?

Comment: You're missing a `...` from the line in my answer, but yes. See the linked example, it has everything you need.

Comment: @iainn, array_map(null, ...array_values($array)); when should we have  you 
three dots  ...array_values($array)